# OpenMp error with parallel for

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

This is my first attempt at using OpenMP. In trying to understand what is private and what is not, after much trial and error I realized that the code works ONLY if there is a print statement that includes `tid = omp_get_thread_num()`. Here is the relevant code chunk.

```
int tid, j;
#pragma omp parallel for private(tid)
for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("thread:%d\n", tid);
        int q, i;
        obj *A = NULL;
        i = is[j];
        A = As[i];
        for (q = qs[i]; q < qs[i + 1]; ++q) {
            int p, r;
            obj *B = NULL, *C = NULL;
            p = ps[q];
            r = rs[p];  
            B = Bs[p];
            C = Cs[r];
            do_the_thing(A, B, C);
   }
}
```

1. `A`, `B` and `C` are pointers to objects stored in an respective arrays (`As`, `Bs` & `Cs`).
2. Loop indices (`j` & `p`) and other integer arrays `is`, `ps`, `qs`, `rs` serve the purpose of indexing object arrays.
3. `As` and `Bs` are read only. `Cs[r]` is the object that gets written to.
4. All relevant variables are declared locally, within respective loops. In any case, `B` is obviously shared with the inner loop, but `A` and `C` are never accessed, even across threads.

Here are the issues:
1. Serial code is well tested and is correct. 
2. `omp parallel for` ALWAYS produces correct result if `tid` is printed: `printf("thread:%d\n", tid);`
3. `omp parallel for` ALWAYS produces incorrect result if the `printf()` is commented out: `//printf("thread:%d\n", tid);` Error is weird. Parts of `C->values` array are correct. Other parts are wrong.

Very likely I failed to include other relevant information to `omp`.

**Update**

1. I was wrong in my original understanding of the problem. `Cs[r]->values` may be written-to at the same time across threads. Putting a `#pragma c critical` now gives the correct answer. There seems to be a significant overhead for doing so. omp version is 3 times slower than the sequential version. But that is a different issue.
2. What I fail to understand is that why including a print statement printing even just the index of the outerloop `printf("%d\n", j)` prevent the error from occurring - with much larger overhead.  How can a print statement alter any other computations?

Comment: Can you give complete example so as to have clear understanding ?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the code you show, so I assume it's in  parts you don't. Please create a [mcve].